# How to search files and use dictionary in Python(SELECT CASE)?

Tags: python

I have files in json_fi and dictionary

```
my_dict = {'ticr_calculated_2':'ticr-2.parquet','ticr_calculated_3':'ticr-3.parquet',\
          'ticr_calculated_4': 'ticr-4.parquet' , 'tick_calculated_2':'tick-2.parquet', \
          'tick_calculated_3':'tick-3.parquet', 'tick_calculated_4':,'tick-4.parquet',}
```

Example of file format

```
tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T08-48-53.json
```

Python does not have Select?Case. I want to choose file by regex pattern and choose from dictionary for same pattern

```
   for f in json_fi:
        if re.match('ticr_calculated_2', f):
```

How to choose now?

```
filepath = basic + my_dict.value
```

Than I call my function

```
mm(f,filepath)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f in json_fi:
    for key, value in my_dict.items():        
        if re.match(key, f):
            filepath = basic + value
            mm(f,filepath)
```

Note that it will be `my_dict.iteritems()` if you are using python 2

Answer (score 0):

So, as I understood it correctly, you want to check if every filename in `json_fi` has a match with an element from `my_dict`.
Couldn't you then do something like:

```
# Iterate over every filename
for f in json_fi:
    for key in my_dict.keys():
        if re.match(key, f):
            filepath = basic + my_dict[key]
            mm(f, filepath
```

I am not 100% sure what are the contents for files `my_dict` and `json_fi`, but that's my best guess.